# How can I save variables to a file? Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm not really very good with Actionscript 3.0 and I was wondering how I can save variables to a file (A .txt), as well as set variables using a button.

What I am trying to do is get a name, date and another name. I have 3 input boxes and I am unsure how to get the text input to be saved into a text file. I need it to create a new file every time it saves so the details of each user is saved (This is my task, it's an induction thingy, nothing bad).

Also, I am unsure how to set variables with the click of a button. Say the button instance name is "next_button" and I want to get it to set a variable that I can call later on. If I click it, the variable will be set to "Contractor", that's what I need.

The start of the "quiz" if you would call it is asking for the name, date and the company they're from. I need those details to be saved to a file.

I also need help with getting a variable to be set with the click of a button. I have 4 buttons on the screen and I want to get the button to change a variable to "Permanent Employee" or "Contractor".

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can also try [**`SharedObject`**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save data using the FileReference Class:

```
var data:String = "JDLKJFSDKJFHS";
var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
file.save(data,"filepath.txt");
```

To set a variable on mouse click:

```
var saveVar:String = "";
var buttons:Array = [button1,button2,button3];
var buttonStrings:Array = ["Contractor","Employee","Slave"];

button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onClick);
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
    var index:int = buttons.indexOf(e.target);
    if (index > 0) saveVar = buttonStrings[index];
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the text I put into the text box saved into the txt file? If there is, that'd be great and if not, are there any other ways?

Comment: You should have a reference to the text box then just do textRef.text to get the string inside of it. If the textboxes are put inside of a movieclip or on the stage then you need to give them an instance name. If they are created in code then their reference is just the variable they are assigned to.

Comment: If the instance name of the input text box is "username" How do I reference it? Where in the actions would it go? (Sorry if I sound kinda stupid, I'm not the best coder out there.)

Comment: Is it in a movieclip or on the stage? If it's on the stage just do username.text to get the text inside of it. If it's in a movieclip, then use the movieclips reference so: movieclipReference.username.text

Comment: I've got the save prompt up and now is there a way I can get it so that the details I've entered are there in the save file name? Currently, where it says filepath.txt , is there a way I can change it? If I enter the name bob, is there a way to change the name of the file to "bob"?

Comment: Just change it to bob.txt. So if you have a textbox for instance with the file name you want, then use: file.save(data, textbox.text + ".txt");